# How can I format my answer in the Stack Exchange mobile app?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, markdown, android-app

I have trying to write an answer to a question from my mobile in the Android Stack Exchange app (I am using [Sony Xperia Z1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Xperia_Z1)). But I saw a simple text box only, not an editor box. See the following image:

[image: Answer edit box screenshot on mobile]

#### Bugs:

- See the "Write your answer" placeholder, the alignment is off. We need to make align it to center of the text box.
- We can't format the answer in the answer box
- I can't upload an image

#### Feature request

- Please change the text box to a proper editor (like the Stack Overflow website answer box)

**Detailed Explanation**

The Formatting header is Working in Question box. But not working in answer box.

See the screen shot, when I ask a question.

[image]

Comment: Have you **tried** typing? The iOS app has a editing toolbar, I'm sure the Android app has one too.

Comment: I took a screen shot, please you can see the box. you can see the keyboard opened in my screen shot, So  I have tried type :) @MartijnPieters

Comment: Why Minus vote? I think the down voter is not take a seriousness :( hmm

Comment: I know next to nothing about how the Android app is supposed to work; I'm sure I saw a screenshot on another report that included the toolbar, though. I'll see what I can dig up; it'll be over on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app).

Comment: Interesting, I found this feature request: [Include desktop style post editing buttons within the android app (especially code format and picture upload)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226238). Poor, poor android users..

Comment: an you show me the screen shot?

Comment: Ah, it is the [*tablet beta*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245731/help-us-test-the-stack-exchange-android-tablet-app) that has the new editing ribbon. Mea Culpa, the feature is coming to a future version instead.

Comment: hmm, that is working for me in question box, not answer box . I am saying  about not question box, I was asking about answer box not working formatting headers

Comment: The editing toolbar comes up just fine for me when answering, _after_ typing the first few characters.

Comment: If you do have toolbar, it's not there on small screens like when I use landscape to get a bigger keyboard. Well the buttons work kind of, they're packed with features and I use the term politely

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5 running Lollipop 5.1.1, on SE app v1.0.68; the toolbar pop-up when writing an answer too. Could you revisit & recheck this issue if it's still applicable?

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

The problem has to do with how the view changes states.  It is visible iff the keyboard is visible AND the markdown editor is focused.  It appears either when the element is focussed or the keyboard appears, whichever happens last.  (In the ask screen, the flow is generally that the keyboard appears (for title), then the body is focussed.  In the answer screen, the flow is that the body is focussed then keyboard appears.)

We track keyboard appearance with a variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7423586/860000) by having the layout resize on keyboard appearance and observing the layout size change.  The problem is that going from `GONE` to `VISIBLE` is a layout change and you're not supposed to perform a layout change during a layout change.  The code attempted to correct for this by first performing the layout change, then calling `postInvalidate()` so it could be corrected in the next layout pass.  I'm guessing this only worked in certain conditions.  Instead, I'm now delaying updating the UI at all until the next main loop pass using `post(Runnable)`